# How to calculate the sum according to first and second column? using shell script

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a file like:

```
ast 6   +   0   2   
ast 6   +   1   20  
ast 7   -   0   0   
ast 7   -   1   24  
ria 366914  +   0   0   
ria 366914  +   0   2
```

It was sorted according to the first and second column. it means that all the same value in 
the 1st and 2nd columns closed to each other.
I want to sum column 4 and column 5 when the first and second column with same value.

```
ast 6   +   1   22      
ast 7   -   1   24      
ria 366914  +   0   2
```

Comment: It should be straightforward using awk. Check whether columns 1 and 2 are the same as previous, and add 4 and 5 into accumulators. When 1 and 2 change, print the totals and reset them.

Comment: Your example doesn't show what to do with column 3 if the values differ. Or will they always be the same when columns 1 and 2 are the same?

Comment: Yes, the column 3 is always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'p != $1 OFS $2{if (NR>1) print p, q, s; p=$1 OFS $2; q=$3 OFS $4; s=$5; next} {s+=$5} END{print p, q, s}' file
ast 6 + 0 22
ast 7 - 0 24
ria 366914 + 0 2
```

Comment: and I modified your script to make it also calculate $4

Comment: awk 'p != $1 OFS $2{if (NR>1) print p, q, r, s; p=$1 OFS $2; q=$3; r=$4; s=$5; next} {s+=$5; r+=$4} END{print p, q, r, s}'

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{str=$1 FS $2;a[str]+=$4;b[str]+=$5;c[str]=$3}END{for (i in a) print i,c[i],a[i],b[i]}' infile |sort -k1,1 -k2,2n

ast 6 + 1 22
ast 7 - 1 24
ria 366914 + 0 2
```